# How to show that $ P(\alpha(G)\ge \frac{n}{2k})\le \frac{1}{2} $ using the above Lemma?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G\in \mathcal{G}(n,p)$ be a Erdos-Renyi random graph. Let $\alpha(G)$ be the maximal number of the independent set of $G$. Here is a Lemma as follows.

> If $p\ge \frac{8 ln n}{r}$ and integer $r\ge 2$, then
> $$
> P(\alpha(G)\ge r)\le \frac{1}{n}
> $$

The proof is as follows. Note that $e^{\frac{1}{2}p(r-1)}\ge e^{pr/4}\ge n^2$ and $1-p\le e^{-p}$. Then
$$
P(\alpha(G)\ge r)\le n^r q^{r(r-1)/2}\le(\frac{n}{n^2})^r\le\frac{1}{n}
$$

---

Question:
I try to show that for every integer $k$, and $p=n^{\epsilon-1}$ with $k\ge 3$ and $0<\epsilon<1/k$, as $n$ large enough

$$
P(\alpha(G)\ge \frac{n}{2k})\le \frac{1}{2}
$$

To get above inequality, I need to use the Lemma. But $r$ is the integer but $n/2k$ is not an integer. Also, if I take $r=\frac{n}{2k}$, then we need another condition that $r=\frac{n}{2k}\ge 2$, how to ensure this one hold?

We already have $p=n^{\epsilon -1}\ge \frac{16 k ln n}{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set $r = \lfloor n / 2k \rfloor$ to get an integer to use in the lemma. As for the second part, you first fix $k$ and the result claimed holds for sufficiently large $k$. So you can simply assume that $n$ is large enough so that $r \geq 2$.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to show that $P(\alpha(G)\ge \frac{n}{2k})\le 1/2$ but not $P(\alpha(G)\ge [\frac{n}{2k}])\le 1/2$.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(\alpha(G) \geq \frac{n}{2k}) \leq \mathbb{P}(\alpha(G) \geq \lfloor \frac{n}{2k} \rfloor)$.

Comment: Does it correct? It seems that $P(\alpha>n/2k)\le P(\alpha>[n/2k])$?

Comment: $\lfloor \frac{n}{2k} \rfloor$ means rounding down. Edit: I think you wrote the same thing I wrote?